# Change tick text in Plotly Surface Plot

Tags: python, plotly

I've created a surface plot to visualise a variable by hour of day and day of week. The plot works, however, I'm unable to change the default tick text (0,1,2,3...) to "Monday" "Tuesday" etc.

```
data = [go.Surface(z=df.values.tolist(), colorscale='Blackbody')]
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        tickmode = 'Array',
        ticktext = Hours, #'Hours' is a list with 24 str elements e.g. "00:00"
        tickvals = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        tickmode = 'Array',
        ticktext = Weekdays, ##'Weekdays' is a list with 7 str elements e.g. "Monday"
        tickvals = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='test.html')
```

Expected - X axis tick marks: ("00:00", "00:01", ...), Y axis tick marks: ("Monday", "Tuesday", ...).

Actual  - X marks: (0, 1, 2, ... 23), Y marks: (0, 1, 2, ... 6)

My DataFrame is a simple day/time matrix with 24 columns (hour) and 7 rows (weekday)

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 7 entries, Monday to Sunday
Data columns (total 24 columns):
00:00    7 non-null float64
01:00    7 non-null float64
02:00    7 non-null float64
---------------------------
21:00    7 non-null float64
22:00    7 non-null float64
23:00    7 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(24)
memory usage: 1.4+ KB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing an outer dictionary containing xaxis and yaxis, solution below:

```
data = [go.Surface(z=df.values.tolist(), colorscale='Blackbody')]
layout = go.Layout(
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(
            tickmode = "Array",
            ticktext = Hours,
            tickvals = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23]
        ),
        yaxis=dict(
            tickmode = "Array",
            ticktext = Weekdays,
            tickvals = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
        )
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='test.html')
```